# Setting app label based on buildvariant

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an Android with multiple `productFlavors`. I'd like the `android:label` for the debug build of, for example `flavor1`, to say `Flavor1 Debug` and the release build to say `Flavor1`.

Without `productFlavors` this is relatively simple, just create a different `string` resource in the debug and release source folders but with `productFlavors`, I don't want to be creating `flavor1Debug`, `flavor2Debug`, etc. folders for each flavor with just one `string` resource in there.

Is there a way to do this ? I'm guessing it requires merging resources somehow but am not sure how.

For extra points, it would be awesome if I could add an overlay to the app icon i.e. merge two images but I realize that might be taking it too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution for this. Basically, you use the following method that copies read the build file, modifies the property value, then rewrites the files.

```
def debugAppRename(variant, labelResource) {
  def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
  def buildtype = variant.buildType
  // Append buildType name to app label
  if(buildtype.debuggable) {
    variant.mergeResources << {
      def valuesFile = "$buildDir/res/all/${flavor.name}/${buildtype.name}/values/values.xml"
      def values = (new XmlParser()).parse(valuesFile)
      values.string.each { m->
        if (m.@name == labelResource) {
          m.value = m.text() + " " + buildtype.name.capitalize()
          new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(valuesFile)))
                .print(values)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The way to use it is:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    debugAppRename(variant, 'app_name') // where `app_name` is the string resource you use for the `app:label` property in your AndroidManifest.xml
}
```

The resulting app will have the buildType name appended to it if it is a debuggable buildType, for e.g. `My App Debug`, `My App Staging`, etc. The `release` build remains unaffected.

I also put it up on a [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/saadfarooq/bec5c58b5ecf2ecd388f).

You can apply it in your `build.gradle` using the `apply from:` directive with the raw gist URL or copy the above to your code (personally I find build scripts become too large so I prefer applying from).